# How to extract Ethernet level data from pcap file?

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I have some pcap files, previously I used tshark combined python to extract source IP address, timestamp, ect.

However, now I open these pcap files in Wireshark. It also contains the VLAN info, VID is the thing I want to extract right now.

I use `tshark -r xx.pcap` in the terminal, it can only show the tcp level info, I can not get this VLAN ID. Does anyone one know how to do it in Python? use some library or tool?

Comment: `tshark -V` dumps the whole packet, or is there more to this question?

Answer (score 2):

the perfect solution is [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

In this example i create a packet with vlan and then print the vlan ID

```
from scapy.all import *
pkt=Ether()/Dot1Q(vlan=0x32)/IP(dst="192.168.1.66")/ICMP()
print pkt[Dot1Q].vlan
```

and this example shows how to read a pcap file and print the VLAN ID

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.utils import *
pkts=rdpcap("filename.pcap")
for pkt in pkts:
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot1Q):
        print pkt[Dot1Q].vlan
```

tested and works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) for that:

```
from scapy.all import *

recs = rdpcap("yourpcap.pcap")

# extract vlan id from first record
for rec in recs:
    dot1q = rec.get_layer(Dot1Q)
    if dot1q is None:
        # not vlan here, skip.
        continue
    print 'Vlanid found:', dot1q.vlan, 'on packet', rec
```

Not tested, but could work. To learn scappy, best is to launch it, and play with auto completion, and read tutorials :)